# Javascript: My <p> Content is Not Appearing When I Append Them With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I've been working on the following problem for a while now.

1. Make a web service request every 1 second to http://courses.acs.uwinnipeg.ca/2909-001/assignments/A2Q2.php
   for 20 seconds. A JSON object will be returned. Count up the amount of circle and rectangle types and display
   the counts. The web service will occasionally return a status of 500 and these should also be counted and
   displayed.

[image: Example output given]

The above is an example of how my output should look like.

Here's what I got coded:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var json;
 var setIntervalCounter = 0;
 var circleCounter = 0;
 var rectangleCounter = 0;
 var errorCounter = 0;
 var repeatRequest = setInterval(function(){
 xhr.onreadystatechange = incrementer();
 xhr.open("GET", "http://courses.acs.uwinnipeg.ca/2909-001/assignments/A2Q2.php");
 xhr.send();
 setIntervalCounter++;
 if (setIntervalCounter === 20){
 clearInterval(repeatRequest)
 }}, 1000);
 
 
 if (setIntervalCounter === 20){
  
  results();
 
 }
 
 //functions
 function incrementer(){
 json = xhr.responseText;
 if (json.includes("circle")){
  circleCounter++;
 }
 else if (json.includes("rectangle")){
  rectangleCounter++;
 }
 else {
  errorCounter++;
 }
 };
 
 function results(){
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  var p2 = document.createElement("p");
  var p3 = document.createElement("p");
  
  p1.innerHTML = "There are " + circleCounter;
  p2.innerHTML = "There are " + rectangleCounter;
  p3.innerHTML = "There are " + errorCounter;
  
  var div = document.getElementById("results");
  
  div.appendChild(p1);
  div.appendChild(p2);
  div.appendChild(p3);
 };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I've fulfilled every criteria specified in the question, but I've run into an issue at the part where I have to display the counts. For some reason my page is blank even though I've appended all the content to my div. Any ideas?

Comment: `xhr.onreadystatechange = incrementer();` ->`xhr.onload= incrementer;`

Comment: Hi, tried that change but my script still runs exactly as before. The content still isn't appearing after the script is finished.

Comment: you need to check `if (setIntervalCounter === 20){` in the callback, not just once up top before it even increments.

Comment: Yup, it sends the request every second for 20 seconds then ends. My counter is also going up as well. The only problem I have is that my results don't appear on my page after the 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code slightly and it works for me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var json;
 var setIntervalCounter = 0;
 var circleCounter = 0;
 var rectangleCounter = 0;
 var errorCounter = 0;
 var repeatRequest = setInterval(function(){
  xhr.onreadystatechange = incrementer();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://courses.acs.uwinnipeg.ca/2909-001/assignments/A2Q2.php");
  xhr.send();
  setIntervalCounter++;
  if (setIntervalCounter === 20){
   clearInterval(repeatRequest);
   results();
  }
 }, 1000);
 
 /*
 if (setIntervalCounter === 20){
  debugger;
  results();
 
 }
 */
 
 //functions
 function incrementer(){
  json = xhr.responseText;
  if (json.includes("circle")){
   circleCounter++;
  }
  else if (json.includes("rectangle")){
   rectangleCounter++;
  }
  else {
   errorCounter++;
  }
 }
 
 function results(){
  debugger;
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  var p2 = document.createElement("p");
  var p3 = document.createElement("p");
  
  p1.innerHTML = "There are " + circleCounter;
  p2.innerHTML = "There are " + rectangleCounter;
  p3.innerHTML = "There are " + errorCounter;
  
  var div = document.getElementById("results");
  
  div.appendChild(p1);
  div.appendChild(p2);
  div.appendChild(p3);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your problem was the execution order of code,
In your code version - this line:

```
if (setIntervalCounter === 20){
```

Was running before the interval count, and it never run again when the counter gets to 20, what I have done that after clearing the interval I call the results() function just after the clearInterval.

If you put break points and debug through the code you will realize the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely understand the issue now.